# How to retrieve XML attributes "two nodes deep" using F# Data's XML Type Provider?

Tags: xml, f#, type-providers, f#-data

I want to retrieve `a` and `b` attributes of let's say (`level2` `name=`) `level2Name4` in (`level1` `name=`) `level1Name2` using the [F# Data's XML Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html) from the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<ROOT>
    <level1 name="level1Name1">
        <level2 name="level2Name1" a="8" b="104" />
        <level2 name="level2Name2" a="85" b="140" />
    </level1>
    <level1 name="level1Name2">
        <level2 name="level2Name3" a="50" b="500" />
        <level2 name="level2Name4" a="376" b="1065" />
        <level2 name="level2Name5" a="10" b="10" />
        <level2 name="level2Name6" a="700" b="700" />
    </level1>
    <level1 name="level1Name3">
        <level2 name="level2Name7" a="502" b="66" />
    </level1>
</ROOT>
```

However, I can't transform / expand `level2` into a map, nor to retrieve the necessary information from there:

```
open System.Xml.Linq
open FSharp.Data

type myXmlType = XmlProvider<"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><ROOT><level1 name="level1Name1"><level2 name="level2Name1" a="8" b="104" /><level2 name="level2Name2" a="85" b="140" /></level1><level1 name="level1Name2"><level2 name="level2Name3" a="50" b="500" /><level2 name="level2Name4" a="376" b="1065" /><level2 name="level2Name5" a="10" b="10" /><level2 name="level2Name6" a="700" b="700" /></level1><level1 name="level1Name3"><level2 name="level2Name7" a="502" b="66" /></level1></ROOT>""">

let myXml = myXmlType.Parse("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><ROOT><level1 name="level1Name1"><level2 name="level2Name1" a="8" b="104" /><level2 name="level2Name2" a="85" b="140" /></level1><level1 name="level1Name2"><level2 name="level2Name3" a="50" b="500" /><level2 name="level2Name4" a="376" b="1065" /><level2 name="level2Name5" a="10" b="10" /><level2 name="level2Name6" a="700" b="700" /></level1><level1 name="level1Name3"><level2 name="level2Name7" a="502" b="66" /></level1></ROOT>""")

let myA, myB =
    myXml.GetLevel1s()
    |> Seq.filter (fun L1 -> L1.Name = "level1Name2")
    |> Seq.initInfinite (fun i L1 -> L1.GetLevel2s())
    ...
```

This is where I am stuck. How to unfold / expand / transform `level2` here? And then, how to retrieve `a` and `b` of(`level2` `name=`) `level2Name4` in (`level1` `name=`) `level1Name2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. The GetXXX() methods return arrays, so you need to flatten the inner level. Instead of `Seq.initInfinite`, which takes an generator function `(int -> 'T)`, you could either use a combination of `Seq.map`and `Seq.concat`, or `Seq.collect` to reduce the nesting by one level:

```
myXmlType.GetSample().GetLevel1s()
|> Seq.filter (fun L1 -> L1.Name = "level1Name2")
|> Seq.collect (fun L1 -> L1.GetLevel2s())
|> Seq.iter (fun L2 -> printfn "%A %A" L2.A L2.B)
```

which prints

```
50 500
376 1065
10 10
700 700
```

**Edit** So you're not interested in the attribute's sequence, but want the attributes of one specific instance as determined by its name? Then we have to search for the element, first in the outer level (may fail), than the inner (may fail too).

```
let myA, myB =
    myXmlType.GetSample().GetLevel1s()
    |> Seq.tryFind (fun L1 -> L1.Name = "level1Name2") 
    |> function
    | None -> failwith "level1Name2 not found"
    | Some L1 ->
        L1.GetLevel2s()
        |> Seq.tryFind (fun L2 -> L2.Name = "level2Name4")
        |> function
        | None -> failwith "level2Name4 not found"
        | Some L2 -> L2.A, L2.B
// val myB : int = 1065
// val myA : int = 376
```

**Edit2** You can combine the two approaches:

```
let myA, myB =
    myXmlType.GetSample().GetLevel1s()
    |> Seq.filter (fun L1 -> L1.Name = "level1Name2")
    |> Seq.collect (fun L1 -> L1.GetLevel2s())
    |> Seq.tryFind (fun L2 -> L2.Name = "level2Name4")
    |> function
    | None -> failwith "level2Name4 not found"
    | Some L2 -> L2.A, L2.B
```

Comment: So after `myXmlType.GetSample().GetLevel1s()
    |> Seq.filter (fun L1 -> L1.Name = "level1Name2")
    |> Seq.collect (fun L1 -> L1.GetLevel2s())
    |> Seq.filter (fun L2 -> L2.Name = "level2Name4")` how do you save (not just print) `a` and `b` attributes to variables? It is still not clear for me.

Comment: Many thanks kaefer, just what an F# neophyte needs to go deeper.